# Human's capacity to withstand extreme heat in dry air

Tags: human-biology, physiology, human-physiology, skin, heat

What is the maximum temperature a human can withstand for short periods of time in an environment with dry air (e.g. oven @+300F, other confined spaces) and what would be the immediate risk of being in such environment be (lung damage, core temperature, etc.).